# How do I get the html login form on Trac to display?

Tags: apache, trac

I installed trac with the account manager plugin and everything works great. I have enabled all of the account manager's components. The html registration form appears but the problem is that the html login form won't. I keep getting the default authentication pop up.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at : http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracOnWindows#a8.AccountManagerPlug-in

may be this is missing in your trac.ini:

```
[Components]
trac.web.auth.loginmodule = disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it has to do with the fact that the bug in AccountManager which appears in trac v0.11.4 still exiss in 0.11.5?

Comment: Which bug is that? I have patched the AccountManagerPlugin for the MessageWrapper issue and still don't get the Login form.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to disabling the built-in login module, make sure your webserver isn't the one blocking access to Trac.  For Apache you'd need a `<Location /trac/login>` entry in your Apache config, and no Apache auth on the `<Location /trac>` portion.

Generally it is easier to debug these sorts of things if we can see the webserver config and the Trac config.